# Squid3 ACL using Linux credentials

Tags: squid, access-control-list

I'm running Squid3 on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 server and have an ACL rule that only allows the 127.0.0.1 ip, ie local users.  I access this through a ssh tunnel.

However, I would like to tighten the ACL so that only certain logged in users are able to use Squid3.  From [www.comfsm.fm - SQUID Frequently Asked Questions: Authentication](http://www.comfsm.fm/computing/squid/FAQ-23.html), it looks like I should be able to setup proxy_auth ACL to check the user's linux username/group.  Would anyone please describe how this would be done?  (I don't want to prompt the user to explicitly login to Squid3.)